# Django - AttributeError when trying to access a field in a Form

Tags: django

I have a form somewhere:

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):
    a_field = forms.CharField()
    not_a_field = 'hello world'
```

When instantiating this, and trying to access the field, I get a

```
>>> from baz.views import FooForm
>>> f = FooForm()
>>> f.not_a_field
'hello world'
>>> f.a_field
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'FooForm' object has no attribute 'a_field'
```

What is going on?

Comment: have you tried initializing f.a_field before calling it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that `Form` is designed, the attributes are removed as attributes and added to the `fields` attribute.  This is done so that we can use declarative syntax to define our `Form`, but can loop through the fields when the time comes.

```
>>> f = FooForm()
>>> f.fields['a_field']
<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x1750350>
```

You can find the logic for this in two places.  `django/forms/forms.py` contains the class `DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass` and the method `get_declared_fields`.  These two bits contain the logic to move everything into the `fields` list.

Comment: I didn't saw any alternative proposed but get_declared_fields is deprecated now.

Answer (score 1):

Form fields are accessable through the 'fields' property.

From shell:

```
>>> f = FooForm()
>>> f.fields['a_field']
```

will return:

```
<django.forms.fields.CharField object at [memory location]>
```

You won't be able to access the field using f.a_field unless it has a value.

Answer (score -1):

that's because a_field isn't initialized
ex:

```
>>> f.a_field = 'hi'
>>> print f.a_field
'hi'
```

you have to add data and perform your save() there